# Strange error with an object declaration and url parameter

Tags: php, object, scope

I meet a strange error when I'm coding my application, I would like to use a parameter in url to change the class declaration of an object in a function, I explain my point of view with code, I have product page :

```
/Product?Page=One
```

Then I do like that to declare an object in product.php :

```
 public function product() {

   $Pagenumber = $_GET['Page']
   if(isset($Pagenumber) && trim($Pagenumber) == 'One'){
   var_dump('test') // give me "test" , and that mean it's OK!
   $object = new class1() 
   }
   if(isset($Pagenumber) && trim($Pagenumber) == 'Two'){

   $object = new class2()

   }
   //then in the first use of object I got an error
   ...
   }
```

The error is :

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: object
```

I tried a lot of possibilities but I got nothing , moreover, I got a strange thing when I do like that, it's works very fine :

```
         $foo = "One"; // string
         $Pagenumber = "One"; 

         settype($foo, "string"); // $foo vaut maintenant 5   (integer)
         settype($Pagenumber, "string");

         if($Pagenumber == $foo){
            $object = new class1()
        }
         $object // I can use the object with no error

       ...
```

and here I remark that the problem is with parameter in link only?

Someone have a better solution to change class declaration with value of parameter URL or any better solution of issue above?

Comment: are you sure about the content of `$Pagenumber` ? you have no `else`, so `$object` may not be defined if it isn't `"one"` or `"two"`...

Answer (score 1):

From your url it looks like you are using url rewriting:

```
/Product?Page=One
```

opens:

```
product.php
```

If you use `.htaccess` for that, you need to make sure you add the `QSA` flag to insure that existing parameters get added to the rewritten url as well.

Apart from that you should make sure that `$object` is always set *or* add error handling when it does not match any of your conditions.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to add error handling if `$object` is not set. It's likely that no URL parameter is provided: that case should be handled accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It would help you provide the line of code where the variable $object is generating the notice, but a guess would be that you wrote $$object instead of $object